# Expected Declaration with UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview

Edit:  I realized why I was being confused by the viewdidload.  The purpose of this exercise was to work with changing images being displayed and I was just playing with the code just to test if it displays.  Now that I put the code for the problem together I have a clearer understanding of what's happening.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func btnNext(_ sender: Any) {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "husky")
    }
```

I'm having trouble loading an image into a single view IOS app.  This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "shiba")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }     

}
```

But I keep getting an "expected declaration" error.  The only way I've gotten it to work so far is to have the imageView.image declaration inside the viewDidload method.

Comment: You could declare the image in place of what you have, put `var shibaImage = UIImage(named: "shiba")` and then in viewDidLoad you attach that image to the imageView, `imageView.image = shibaImage`

Comment: You are misunderstanding (or maybe just got confused) about a very basic OOP (Object Oriented Programming) concept - instantiation. While your `imageView` is declared in InterfaceBuilder or IB (it also could be in code) it really doesn't "exist" until `viewDidLoad` is executed. So how can you actually *set* an image until then? Xcode errors - particularly build errors - are pretty good. You need to listen to what they are saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `imageView.image = UIImage(named: "shiba")` inside of the `viewDidLoad()` function.

A class in swift is made up of a series of declarations. Those declarations can be variables, let constants, functions, ext. So when you put `imageView.image = UIImage(named: "shiba")` directly inside your class, swift is expecting that line to be declaring something (var, let, func). By putting your statement inside of `viewDidLoad()` you are saying that statement should be executed whenever `viewDidLoad()` is called. `viewDidLoad()` is called when all the outlets are connected and before the view is visible to the users, which is a good time to set images for image views like in your case.

Comment: This *may* b correct, but **why**? Don't just give the correct answer, explain it. Help everyone else who may need help on this understand *why* this is the correct answer.

Comment: @dfd you're right, I have edited my answer to try to add a little more context.

Comment: For the record, I never down-voted your answer. It's correct! Just needed more. (And posted an OP comment as it was correctly marked as a duplicate.) And honestly? Looking at the dup link, which *was* way worse than your answer, means I now should up-vote it! You explained things and even posted code. The dup link? Ow. No help at all.

Comment: I see where I was getting so confused.  The purpose of the program is to demonstrate how to change an image in an image view, but I ended up just confusing myself by trying to test the UIImageview rather than just work on the problem as a whole.  Thank you.